# Parallel bgl latency and performance

Tags: boost

I'm developing an application that does computations per vertex of a graph. The main problem here is that of latency as each computation is rather small.  For example, each computation might take 10ms to execute by itself, so PGBL should not add any significant latency to the process.

I can code my own barebones graph routines to accomplish this task. Of course PBGL has many more features that would be nice to have. For example, I would like to potentially even off load some computations to the "cloud" when latency is not an issue.

So basically, what is the overhead of computations across vectors on a cpu or multi-core cpu? Also, would it be possible to off load vertex computations to a gpu in the future?

I've never used PGBL but ran across it in the boost library and it caught my eye as something that might be near perfect for my application except for potentially latency issues.

For example, what would the performance difference be between a very simple tree that is divided up into n branches which computations of each branch ran on a separate core vs using PBGL? (for small computation times, obviously the larger the computation the less of a difference)

Answer (score 1):

The Parallel BGL is primarily a distributed-memory library.  There is a research version that has incorporated shared-memory parallelism as well.  In the longer term we may add accelerator support presuming accelerator memory models ever support atomics in inner-kernels, overlapping output write sets, and other complex behavior needed to support graph algorithms conducive to other sorts of parallelization.  The primary goal is to find a single parallel abstraction that allows graph algorithms expressed using it to be parallelized using a variety of hardware.

At any rate, it sounds like you're looking for a primarily shared-memory parallel graph library for which the Parallel BGL is likely to be a poor fit.  At the moment you'd have to run multiple MPI ranks which definitely doesn't satisfy your 'low latency' constraint.  There's been some interest in a shared-memory and/or SIMD version of BGL over the years, but nothing ever came of it.  With the addition of more shared-memory parallel libraries to Boost (Lockfree, various SIMD implementations and containers, etc.) the effort required to implement some sort of shared-memory parallel BGL is getting pretty low so maybe it will happen one of these days.